# Yii foreign keys

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii

In my web application I have two tables name "producer_offer" and "book_vegetable". The "producer_offer_id"  is the foreign key in  id column of "producer-offer" table.
Now I want to  see a column called "booked_quantity" of   "book_vegetable"  table inside "producer_offer" table.
How should I proceed ..
Should I assign
     `book_vegetable.producer_offer_id=producer_offer.id`
       How should it be done in the Yii way?

```
I tried this in the action create of book_vegetable controller but it's not working.
```

Any body kindly help me to resolve this issue.
My relation function for producer_offer table

```
public function relations()
    {
        return array(
 'producerOfferBookVegetableRelation'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'BookVegetable','id'),   
)
}
```

My relation function for book_vegetable table

```
public function relations()
    {
'producerOffer' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'ProducerOffer', 'producer_offer_id'),
        );
    }
```

I tried this in action create of book_vegetable controller but not working.

```
$model=new BookVegetable;
    $producerOffer=new ProducerOffer;


    if(isset($_POST['BookVegetable']))
    {
    $model->attributes=$_POST['BookVegetable'];
    $model->booked_by=Yii::app()->user->id;
    $model->producer_offer_id=$produceroffer->id;
    if($model->save())
    $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
    }

    $this->render('create',array(
    'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

But the error I am getting is

```
Undefined variable: produceroffer
```

Any one please help me with this .I have no idea what to do.Thanks in advance.

Comment: this will help you. http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/19/how-to-use-a-single-form-to-collect-data-for-two-or-more-models/

Comment: Ya thks tat really got me closer

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of the action you create `$producerOffer` instance but then try to access it as `$produceroffer` (with 'o' instead 'O'), that is why you get "undefined variable" error.